# Problem with background image and <th> white space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a Table and in the `<thead>` I have a background image, I have a coubple of rows and `<th>` this is the structure of my markup:

(Im using bootstrap by the way)

```
<table className="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colSpan="12">
                    <h3 className="table-title">POST APOCALYPTIC HIGHWAY</h3>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr className="attributes">
                  <th className="position"></th>
                  <th className="img d-none d-sm-table-cell"></th>
                  <th className="fullname"></th>
                  <th className="bib text-center">Bib</th>
                  <th className="age d-none d-sm-table-cell text-center">
                    Age
                  </th>
                  <th className="gender text-center">Gender</th>
                  <th className="time text-center">Time</th>
                  <th className="score text-center">Score</th>
                </tr>
                {/** Ghost row to simulate margin */}
                <tr style={{ height: "10px" }}>
                  <th colSpan="12"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
```

Im applying a background image through CSS to the `<thead>` this way:

```
.leaderboard thead {
  background-image: url(./images/black-square-pattern.jpeg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  color: #fff;
}
```

I also make sure there's 0 padding and margin in the `<th>` elements

```
.leaderboard thead th {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

It looks okay in desktop but for some reason when I test it in Google chrome inspecter the different mobile previews I see some tiny white spaces between the cells, I cannot find why it's happening, any idea how to fix it? I also tested in Safari and the same happens.

[image: white spaces between th elements]

Comment: CSS is a beast. Try `font-size: 0` and `line-height: 0` outside the table.

Comment: I don't understand, I have content outside the table I cannot do that, also don't understand what's the point...

Comment: Because sometimes spaces exist due to font size and line height. You will need to (re)set the line height again for all children.

Comment: Also, another tip would be to use Devtools to find exactly where the padding came from.

Comment: Dev tools is what Im using...

Comment: Hmm... does Bootstrap make the borders white? Maybe do `border:0` for the table or whatever elements have those gaps.

Comment: I already did that, check the styles I shared in the quesiton...

Comment: Rather than having this back-and-forth I'd appreciate if you pointed out the issue in a minimal reproducible example. The screenshot does not match the code you provided.